# Substring substitution in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, substring

I am trying to make a function that replace a substring inside of a String for other substring that are contained in these two arrays.

```
String[] A = {"kk", "pp", "tt", "k", "p", "t", "rt", "lt", "nt", "nk", "mp"};
String[] B = {"k",  "p",  "t",  "",  "v", "d", "rr", "ll", "nn", "ng", "mm"};
```

The idea is if I have a String that contains only one of the array 'A' then substitute for its equivalent (in index) from 'B'.

I tried using StringBuilder's indexOf but is not working. I tried something with patterns too, but I am not very familiar with regular expressions. How is the best way for you to do this?

An example;

```
String s = "auttaa";
myfunction(s);
```

now `s = "autaa"`

Comment: I recommend posting your full attempt in order to get help.

Comment: In Addition, You could post your expected result after the substitution in order to make it more clear what you are working on.

Comment: How you plan to handle following case: assume the string contains `kk`: it first be substituted by `k`, and later the `k` will be substituted by `v`. What have you in mind to handle that case?

Comment: How would you handle `ttt` as `trr` or `rrt`?

Comment: I dont understand the question properly . Please add input expected output and what you have tried .

Comment: @SubOptimal  it won't be such case

Comment: @ABR I believe you should more explain the rules of the substitution. Is there any kind of precedence of the patterns? For example: `rtt` - will if be `tt` as `tt` comes before `rt` in `A[]` or will it be `rrt` as `rt` in the string is the first pattern which is part of `A[]`?

Comment: oh yes, I should explain before, threre is not posibility of  rtt nor ttt because these strings are Finnish verbs and  as far I know, there is no such thing like three consonants together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option: use a

```
HashMap<String, String>
```

As "key" use the values from array A; the corresponding "value" comes from array B. (or as pointed out by others: a LinkedHashMap in case order is relevant )

Then iterate over the hashmap; and use `replaceAll` to replace all occurrences of hashmap.key with hashmap.value. ( http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm )

By doing it that way, you are open for changes like adding/removing of  substitution rules.

Another advantage when using a map (over using two arrays) is the fact, that pattern and replacement are "more strongly coupled". When using two arrays, there is always a certain risk, that for some stupid reason, the arrays end up with different lengths at some point. Which of course, only becomes visible at runtime. But when you are always specifying your rules as pairs ... then you can't up with more patterns than replacements.

Using a hashmap makes it also very easy to **change** the pattern/replacement rules quite easily (just provide a different map that has other entries).

Comment: I'd suggest using `LinkedHashMap` instead if the order of replacement matters.